# Problems with audio in cocos2d-javascript on mobile devices

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find some documentation for audio support for cocos2d-javascript.
Preloading audio and playing them with the standard method using mp3 or ogg formats:

```
var audioEngine = cc.AudioEngine.getInstance();
audioEngine.playEffect(s_sound);
// s_sound is a reference to a preloaded audio resource
```

works perfectly in all browsers. But when you load the browser on a device, let's say iphone 4s retina, no audio plays, or at least it seems no audio plays for sounds longer than a few seconds. I haven't found anything stating specifically what limitations there may be in device support, nor do I see an attempt to resolve this in anyone's example games like [Moon Warriors](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/06/03/Cocos2D-HTML-release-a-tech-demo-Moon-Warriors.aspx) - which also does not play audio on the iphone 4s.

I am attempting to play multiple sounds simultaneously.

Each sound having problems is over 15 seconds long and is a file greater than 500k

All audio is definitely loaded since the game does not appear unless they are

Each audio track is a layer for the background music of a guitar hero type game. This is why they are over 500k and longer than 15 seconds.

Perhaps someone here has had similar issues and may know of a way to guarantee audio plays on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acceptable answer thus far is to us [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js) and [HowlerAudioEngine.js](https://github.com/many20/cocos2d-html5-howler/blob/009b954668c7bbb5f81d847a4edfb9ef07fa4d66/HowlerAudioEngine.js)

I load both files in my script loader, then modified Platform/HTML5/CocosDenshion/SimpleAudioEngine.js -

```
cc.AudioEngine.getInstance = function () {
    if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
        if (!this._instance) {
            this._instance = new cc.HowlerAudioEngine();
            this._instance.init();
        }
    } else {
        if (!this._instance) {
            this._instance = new cc.AudioEngine();
            this._instance.init();
        }
    }
    return this._instance;
};
```

Notice `window.devicePixelRatio > 1` where I detect retina display or hd in general. This can be substituted with any proven variety of detecting "mobile" - However, `sys.platform` and `cc.config.deviceType` always returned "browser" for me so I resorted to pixel ratio for now since my testing device will return true for that.

The cons, however, are that there is still substantial delay in the delivering of sound fx. I can compensate for that for the most part, so this is better than nothing. Also, I haven't found the tolerance threshold for audio files (play time or data length). I do know that my longer tracks of about 3 minutes don't play even in howler, but my 1 minute tracks do.

If you have anything that is better, more reliable or just an addition to this, please post it. There isn't enough support for cocos2d-javascript yet so everything helps.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, I am able to play sound on all browser except Mobile Safari,
I am using Cocos2dx 3.10 version of js , I am unable to find the SimpleAudioEngine.js file here, I have cc.Audio.js file.

Can you help me with that now?

Comment: Looks like things have changed since this issue came up. I looked over 3x and it looks like the audio is handled in /cocos/audio/include/SimpleAudioEngine.h though I cannot guarantee the structure is still the same. You may need to modify the sample code here to work with whatever that class is doing now.